# how to get value in <td>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td class='type'> Type name </td>
    <td class='number'> 102030 </td>
    <td class='software'> 1.0-Alpha </td>
    <td ><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button>
</tr>
<script>
    $(".btnSelect").on('click',function() {
        var tdNumber = $(this).find('.number').html();
        var data = $(this).find('.number').html();
        alert(data);
    })
</script>
```

If I clicked order button show error **undefined** , what wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st:** close the `</td>` tag in `<td ><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button>`

**2nd:** you need to use `.closest('tr').find`

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class='type'> Type name </td>
    <td class='number'> 102030 </td>
    <td class='software'> 1.0-Alpha </td>
    <td ><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ // you may need to use document ready
    $(".btnSelect").on('click',function(){
      var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('.number').html();
      alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have few mistake in your html dom.

```
<tr>
    <td class='type'> Type name </td>
    <td class='number'> 102030 </td>
    <td class='software'> 1.0-Alpha </td>
    <td><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button>
</tr>
```

`button` is not wrapped with `td` and `tr` is not wrapped with `table` and in your jQuery

```
$(".btnSelect").on('click', function() {
    var tdNumber = $(this).find('.number').html();
    var data = $(this).find('.number').html();
    alert(data);
});
```

there is event on `button` which is inside the `tr`, note that you can do find from child to parent. i.e. `$(this).find('.number').html();` here `$(this)` is the object of clicked button and you are searching the siblings of the parent i.e. `tr` you can review the following example which is written based on your code that you have provided.

```js
$(".btnSelect").on('click', function() {
    var data = $(this).parent().siblings('.number').text();
    alert(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='type'> Type name </td>
        <td class='number'> 102030 </td>
        <td class='software'> 1.0-Alpha </td>
        <td><button class='btnSelect'>Order</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to select any of the element of same tree you must go to root and then find it.

in html dom element to go to root you have to use closest() function and for find from root you have to use find() function

use this

```
$(".btnSelect").on('click',function(){
    var tdNumber = $(this).closest('tr').find('.number').html();
    var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('.number').html();
    alert(data);
});
```